# Attaching an event handler to children, the parent, and the document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Here's what I want. There are several boxes on the page. Each box has children that include some clickable divs and text. When the user clicks on the clickable divs an alert should show up saying that the div was clicked. If they click on the text nothing should happen. Here is where it gets tricky for me.

When they click on the box, the box should have a class called `open` and when they click on something that is not a box or the children of the box, the class `open` should be removed.  If they click on the clickable div that should have no effect of the class of the box.

So if the user clicks on another box the first box should still have the `open` class and the new box should have the `open` class as well but if they click on the header or body or anything else besides the boxes, the `open` class should be removed. Remember if the clickable div is clicked that should trigger an appropriate alert.

It looks like there is a lot of event targeting here and I was wondering if you had a good solution.

Just for demonstration purposes please make it so that if the box has an `open` class change the box's background to green. If they click something else like the header or body or other div the box should have steelblue (original color). if they click the clickable child div the background of the box should be green and an alert should be triggered.

Here is some code:

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  //is there somthing like:
  // if `this` is not the box or children of box remove the
  // class `open` from box. this way if they click on header or body I could remove 
  //the `open` class from box
  if (e.target == this) {
    $(".box").removeClass("open")
  } else if ($(e.target).hasClass("box")) {
    $(e.target).addClass("open")
  }
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("test1")) {
    alert("test1")
  }
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("test2")) {
    alert("test2 clicked")
  }
  if ($(".box").hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).css("background", "green")
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 4em 5em;
  background: steelblue;
  width: 15em;
  height: 8em;
  padding: .1em;
}
.clicker {
  width: 5em;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>this is the box</p>
  <p class="test1 clicker">Test click</p>
  <p class="test2 clicker">Test click 2</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>this is the box</p>
  <p class="test1 clicker">Test click</p>
  <p class="test clicker">Test click 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just tweaking the the conditions should do it like

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  //is there somthing like:
  // if `this` is not the box or children of box remove the
  // class `open` from box. this way if they click on header or body I could remove 
  //the `open` class from box

  var $target = $(e.target);

  var $clicker = $target.closest('.clicker');
  if ($clicker.length) {
    if ($clicker.hasClass("test")) {
      $('#clicked').html("test")
    } else if ($clicker.hasClass("test1")) {
      $('#clicked').html("test1")
    } else if ($clicker.hasClass("test2")) {
      $('#clicked').html("test2")
    }
  }

  var $box = $target.closest('.box');
  if ($box.length) {
    $box.addClass('open');
  } else {
    $('.box.open').removeClass('open');
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 4em 5em;
  background: steelblue;
  width: 15em;
  height: 8em;
  padding: .1em;
}
.box.open {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.clicker {
  width: 5em;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">header:
  <div id="clicked"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>this is the box</p>
  <p class="test1 clicker">Test click</p>
  <p class="test2 clicker">Test click 2</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>this is the box</p>
  <p class="test1 clicker">Test click</p>
  <p class="test clicker">Test click 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, You are very helpful. Keep up the good work  on stackoverflow.